# Summing By Count

Tags: sql, t-sql, count, sum, case

I'm trying to create a Summation based on the Count number for a particular column.  If you looks at the last line in the Select below you'll see that I tried implementing a `CASE` statement.  However, it produces all `NULL` values.  Which I believe I understand why (each row has a unique set of values) but I'm not sure how to fix my problem.

```
SELECT 
    TotalFilesProduced.ReviewDate,
    TotalFilesProduced.FileReviewedByUserID,
    TotalFilesProduced.FileSource,
    TotalFilesProduced.FilesIndexed TotalIndexed,
    TotalFilesProduced.FileNumberofPages TotalFileNumberofPages,
    TotalFilesProduced.FilesProduced,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT FileReviewedByUserID) > 1 THEN SUM(TotalFilesProduced.FilesIndexed) END
FROM 
(SELECT 
    CAST(ibfp.FileReviewedDate AS DATE) ReviewDate,
    ibfp.FileReviewedByUserID,
    FileSource,
    COUNT(*) FilesProduced,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ibf.InboundFileID) FilesIndexed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ibfp.FromPage = ibfp.ToPage THEN 1
    ELSE ibfp.ToPage-ibfp.FromPage + 1 END) [FileNumberofPages]
FROM 
    dbo.InboundFilePartitions ibfp
    INNER JOIN dbo.InboundFiles ibf ON ibfp.InboundFileID = ibf.InboundFileID
WHERE
        CAST(ibfp.FileReviewedDate AS DATE) >= '10/22/2014'
    and CAST(ibfp.FileReviewedDate AS DATE) <= '10/22/2014'
    and ibf.ProjectID in (110)
GROUP BY
    CAST(ibfp.FileReviewedDate AS DATE),
    ibfp.FileReviewedByUserID,
    FileSource 
) TotalFilesProduced
GROUP BY 
    TotalFilesProduced.ReviewDate,
    TotalFilesProduced.FileReviewedByUserID,
    TotalFilesProduced.FileSource,
    TotalFilesProduced.FilesIndexed,
    TotalFilesProduced.FileNumberofPages,
    TotalFilesProduced.FilesProduced
```

Here is an example for further clarification - here the UserID 1036 producing a `NULL` is fine since it appear only once but for 804 - I would like to sum the `TotalIndexed` column so the `NULL` area should read 139 (for both instances that 804 appears)

```
ReviewDate | FilereviewedByUserID | FileSource | TotalIndexed | TotalFileNumberofPages | FilesProduced | (No Column Name) /*My Sum*/
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-10-22 | 804                  | 1          | 1            | 67                     | 1             | NULL
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-10-22 | 1036                 | 1          | 1            | 17                     | 1             | NULL
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-10-22 | 804                  | 2          | 138          | 3322                   | 184           | NULL
```

Comment: Because `FileReviewedByUserID` and `FilesIndexed` are in your `GROUP BY` statement these sums will never be more than one. Can you clarify what you're trying to count?

Comment: The FilereviewedByUserID - if the user appears more than once (count - I decided to use) then sum their TotalIndexed column

Comment: For the third time. With the group by the count will never be > 1.  Voting to close as it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it any clearer - if a UserID is shown more than once - I would like the TotalIndexed column shown above to be SUMMED together.  I understand that the Grouping is making it not sure - but the query wouldn't even run without the Grouping - since I'm using a Count and a Sum in the CASE.

Comment: No you have not explained what you want.  In clear language IN the question explain what you want.   Use a group by to get a query to run is not fixing anything.

Comment: This is no longer an issue I solved it myself

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment
This will always be false

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT FileReviewedByUserID) > 1
```

Because of

```
GROUP BY ibfp.FileReviewedByUserID
```

And you have some other strange stuff

```
        CAST(ibfp.FileReviewedDate AS DATE) >= '10/22/2014'
    and CAST(ibfp.FileReviewedDate AS DATE) <= '10/22/2014'
```

is the same as

```
CAST(ibfp.FileReviewedDate AS DATE) = '10/22/2014'
```

More strange stuff

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ibfp.FromPage = ibfp.ToPage THEN 1
    ELSE ibfp.ToPage-ibfp.FromPage + 1 END) [FileNumberofPages]
```

is the same as

```
SUM(ibfp.ToPage-ibfp.FromPage + 1) [FileNumberofPages]
```

not sure what you are trying to do but a group by on a group by is not common

Comment: This is actually me just simplifying a much larger query.  Hence the Group By in the From and another Group By

Comment: Also their is usually a range of dates captured - not just one day.  In addition, didn't think to simplify the Page thing - but now I see that I can :P